# Image won't change in picturebox, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I'm trying to code it so that i can create a picture box from a method in a class. However when my picture box is drawn it doesn't display any image, it only shows a white square of the specified dimensions in the specified location.

Here is the code which i am using to create said picture box:

```
 Public Sub DrawEnemy(ByRef formInstance)
        Dim enemypic As New PictureBox

        enemypic.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\fboi1\Enemy.Png")
        enemypic.Width = 64
        enemypic.Height = 64
        enemypic.Location = New Point(Me.EnemyPosX, EnemyPosY)
        enemypic.Visible = True
        formInstance.Controls.Add(enemypic)

    End Sub
```

And here is where i am calling the method from:

```
Dim Enemy1 As New computerControlled(1, 1)
        Enemy1.DrawEnemy(Me)
```

Comment: You probably mean `Public Sub DrawEnemy(ByVal formInstance as Form)` (or just `Public Sub DrawEnemy(formInstance as Form)`)

Comment: Yep... definitely no reason to pass ByRef here, and you should definitely specify the type (and _turn on Option Strict for goodness sake!)_. Remember: **ByVal still passes references**... it's just the reference itself that has it's value copied.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the byval, i fixed it. Also, while the white box remains i noticed that when i drag the console window suddenly the white box turns into the image i wanted. Is this a problem with vb or still my code?

Comment: "when i drag the console window"  What console window?  What type of project did you start with? It should have been a WinForms project, which doesn't have a console window...

Comment: What size is your image?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following code in your `DrawEnemy()` method:

```
enemypic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```

Answer (score 0):

> When i drag the console window suddenly the white box turns into the image i wanted.

---

Aha! This means the code is not causing the form to be repainted. We can trigger that by calling the `Invalidate()` function.

```
Public Sub DrawEnemy(formInstance As Form)
    Dim enemypic As New PictureBox

    enemypic.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\fboi1\Enemy.Png")
    enemypic.Width = 64
    enemypic.Height = 64
    enemypic.Location = New Point(Me.EnemyPosX, EnemyPosY)
    enemypic.Visible = True
    formInstance.Controls.Add(enemypic)

    formInstance.Invalidate()
End Sub
```

If you're calling this several times in a loop, you would instead handle this after the loop, where you also block repainting (to prevent flickering) until the loop is finished.

```
form.SuspendLayout()
For Each enemy In ...
    '...
    DrawEnemy(form)
Next
form.Invalidate()
form.ResumeLayout()
```

It's also possible you only need to `Invalidate()` the picturebox.